# PHP MySQL - select where id not equal to two one of 2 ids

Tags: php, sql, pdo, equals

So I'm trying to pick 2 rows randomly but the id isn't allowed to be equal to x or equal to y.

That's what I tried so far:

```
  $statment = $db -> "SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 WHERE 
              NOT(id = ?) OR WHERE NOT(id=?)";
  $statement->execute(array($player1, $player2));
```

But getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: what are you getting as result?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Um, you have a string where a method (probably `prepare()`)should be. How has no one spotted this yet????

Comment: may i ask what is $db? localhost,username,password,database? and what do you have written in your code where you have the questionmark?

Comment: @JohnConde: I spotted it late, but 16 min ago.

Comment: So i tried the prepare method.

Comment: And..........???

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on null in

Comment: `$statment` != `$statement`

Comment: ok thank you guys. It works now. I changed the sql code, added the prepare method and renamed $statment to $statement

Comment: am wondering if all this was the wrong variable to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `AND` to make sure it is not equal `<>` to both:

```
WHERE id <> ? AND id <> ?
```

Or check if it is not `IN` a list:

```
WHERE id NOT IN(?, ?)
```

And I'm not sure about the order of the SQL statement, try:

```
SELECT * FROM player WHERE id <> ? AND id <> ?
         ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Also, you're missing something like maybe `prepare`:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM player WHERE id <> ? AND id <> ?
                                   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: still getting : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: So you didn't mention that.  Your object syntax is wrong.

Comment: [you missed this..........](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736093/php-mysql-select-where-id-not-equal-to-two-one-of-2-ids#comment80419617_46736093)

Comment: Damn, I knew this question was trouble from the start :-(

Comment: .................yep. First thing I spotted.

Answer (score -1):

Use `NOT IN`. You're also missing the call to `prepare()`.

```
$statment = $db ->prepare("SELECT * FROM player
                    WHERE id NOT IN (?, ?)
                    ORDER BY RAND()
                    LIMIT 2");
```

Also, the order of clauses in a `SELECT` statement is:

```
SELECT
FROM
JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
LIMIT
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"SELECT * FROM player ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in

Comment: Not my dv here, but [you missed this..........](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736093/php-mysql-select-where-id-not-equal-to-two-one-of-2-ids#comment80419617_46736093).